# Input of anonymous composite types is not implemented - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, anonymous, composite-types

I have a table with an XML column. The XML can contain an optional link element.

```xml
<Link ReasonCode="MultiLabel">
  <UUID>1d177dee-1da4-4451-b175-396666afc370</UUID>
</Link>
```

I want to fetch all records from the table that do not have link element. From those records that have the link element, I want only the DISTINCT records fetched. If two records have the same link element, skip the second occurrence. The query that I tried,

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT cast((xpath('/Data/Link', xmldata)) AS TEXT) 
FROM tblData AS link 
WHERE link != '{}'
```

> ERROR:  input of anonymous composite types is not implemented

1. What is it that I am doing wrong here that causes the above mentioned error? The query works fine without the `WHERE` clause.
2. In addition to this I want to use an order by clause before the `DISTINCT` method starts processing the results. Again, I messed up with the syntax of using order by and distinct together, and I got an error.

How do I achieve ordering of the results based on the value of a column in the table, for this query?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the expression `link != '{}'` the alias `link` refers to the *table*, not a single column (because of `tblData AS link`).

Postgres allows to refer to the complete row of a table by using the table name (or table alias). The error is telling you that you can't compare a complete row with a single array value.

You need something like this:

```
select distinct cast(xpath('/Data/Link', xmldata) AS TEXT) as linkdata
from data 
where cast(xpath('/Data/Link', xmldata) AS TEXT) <> '{}';
```

Unfortunately it's not possible to use a column alias in the `where` clause. If you want to avoid repeating the expression, use a derived table:

```
select distinct linkdata 
from (
  select cast(xpath('/Data/Link', xmldata) AS TEXT) as linkdata
  from data 
) t 
where linkdata <> '{}';
```

But as you are only expecting a *single* link anyway, the following might better:

```
select distinct linkdata 
from (
  select (xpath('/Data/Link', xmldata))[1] as linkdata
  from data 
) t 
where linkdata is not null;
```

`xpath()` returns an array, the expression `(xpath(..))[1]` gets the first element of that array, if there is no such element, it returns null. Maybe you event want `xpath('/Data/Link/UUID/text()')` to only get the actual UUID, rather than the complete XML node - but that's not clear from the example you provided.

Comment: Well that has cleared up the mistake I did with aliasing. However, I want to fetch all records that do not have the link element at all. I want to apply distinct only on those records that have the link element, which is optional.

Comment: I will go with the last option that you have suggested. But is there a difference in performance in using a derived table and repeating the cast expression? Or is it only to avoid repeating the expression?

Answer (score 0):

I got the error below:

> ERROR:  input of anonymous composite types is not implemented

When I tried to create the array of rows with `::RECORD[]` or `::RECORD` as shown below:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY['(John,Smith)','(David,Miller)']::RECORD[];
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY['(John,Smith)'::RECORD,'(David,Miller)'::RECORD];
```

So, I used `ROW()` instead of `::RECORD[]` or `::RECORD` as shown below, then I could create the array of rows without error. *The type of the array below is `RECORD[]`:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY[ROW('John','Smith'),ROW('David','Miller')];
```